# Relativistic and rest mass of a photon

Tags: photons, mass

I have done some calculations to get relativistic mass and rest mass of a photon.
Are my calculations correct?
If Yes how much significance do they really have in physics?

This image has calculations for rest mass i.e m<sub>0</sub>
[image]

This image has calculations for relativistic mass

[image]

Sorry for I have written proton instead of photon in calculations . Hope you understand.

Comment: The answer you *expect* and the answer you *get* don't have to be the same.  Many people tried to determine an upper limit for the photon mass and [this paper](https://www.princeton.edu/~romalis/PHYS312/Coulomb%20Ref/Photonmasslimits.pdf) discusses the actual methods used.

Comment: The relativistic mass of the photon is very archaic and completely incorrect conception... I don't understand why did you waste your time...

Comment: We have MathJax active on the site so that you can typeset mathematic in a $\LaTeX$ math-mode-alike language. We strongly discourage photographed or scanned images of text because such content is neither searchable to editable.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Welcome to Physics! Please note that we do have an [equation editor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) built into the site, which can help improve readability of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be true... if the photon did have $m_0$, but it actually doesn't.

Check that it makes no sense to have a particle with infinite mass. Instead, if you write $m_0=0$, then you get $0/0$, which is undetermined.

And you solve that using the other great formula. It's actually one of the key formulas of Sp.Rel.:

$E^2 =p^2 c^2 +m_o^2c^4$

For a photon, it's just $E^2 =p^2 c^2$ or $E=pc$, which does make sense. The energy is only due to momentum, and not due to rest mass. It depends on the frequency because $p=\hbar k$.